# Testing a schedule Event does occurs event if it doesn't change the State of the Saga

Tags: masstransit

I have a schedule event that trigger an email reminder after a certain period of time (but it doesn't change the state of the saga).
When I try to test:

```
 var formRequest = WhenAFormRequestIsCreated.BuildFormRequest();
        
 await TestHarness.Bus.Publish(formRequest);

 var existsId = await SagaHarness.Exists(formRequest.CorrelationId, x => x.Created);
 Assert.IsTrue(existsId.HasValue, "Saga did not exist");

 await AdvanceSystemTime(TimeSpan.FromDays(3.5));
        
 //How to await the event occurs?
 //without using the sagaTestHarness because in the final it doesn't change state
        
 NotificationGatewayMock.ThenDirectNotificationsWasSent(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the SagaHarness to wait for the 2nd event of type SendNotification with this call

```
        Assert.IsTrue(await SagaHarness.Consumed.SelectAsync<SendNotification>(m =>
            (m.MessageObject as SendNotification).Notification
            .Variables["IsReminder"].Value.DefaultValue == bool.TrueString).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the scheduled message is consumed by the saga:

```cs
await SagaHarness.Consumed.Any<WhateverMessageWasScheduled>();
```

For a specific message, if there is a distinguishing property:

```cs
await consumer.Received
    .SelectAsync<Whatever>(received => received.Context.Message.SomeProperty == someValue)
    .Any();
```

Or even:

```cs
await consumer.Received.SelectAsync<Whatever>().Take(2);
```

Comment: What if I want to capture the second event of such a type.
My use case is on creation I send an initial email (with a publish because I want to have retry on operation if email provider is down).
Then after X days, I send another one (SchedulePublish).
The consumed works, but I want to capture the second event.
Any example of how to build a ReceivedMessageFilter?

Comment: 2 questions:

1-How do you get the consumer object? Through the 
TestHarness.GetConsumerHarness<Whatever>()                                                      

2-What if my event is not handle by a Consumer, it's directly in the Saga.

Comment: the same features exist on the saga harness.

Comment: This doesn't work for me:
SagaHarness.Consumed.SelectAsync<SendNotification>(
                           r => (r.MessageObject as SendNotification).Notification
                               .Variables["IsReminder"].Value.DefaultValue == bool.TrueString)

Comment: This also doesn't work:
await consumer.Received.SelectAsync<SendNotification>().Take(2);

Comment: In both case, it's just not waiting for the second Event to occur, hence when I validate 
NotificationGatewayMock.ThenDirectNotificationsWasSent();
It doesn't work.

Comment: You're welcome to submit a standalone repository on GitHub that shows what you're struggling with. At this point, the question has gone beyond SO's usefulness.

Comment: I'll do so thanks Chris ;-)

Comment: Here's a link to the problem:
https://github.com/oquirion/MassTransitBug

Comment: Is the test supposed to fail? It passes when I run it.

Comment: It's a race condition. If you put a break point on the last line of the test it normally fails

Comment: I've added a Sleep in event handling in the Saga, to make in consistent.

Comment: I think I've found the problem:
Each Test which play with
   await AdvanceSystemTime(timespan);
Should be separate into their own class because SytemTime is shared upon all test in the same class and for whichever reason (parallelism?) when I have more then one the second test fails consistently, but pass consistently when alone in the class.

Comment: Not a problem, just proper test design. Putting multiple tests in a class with shared test setup is always going to cause problems.